Setting up fake worker failed: \"Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.mjs"
I am facing the issue after deployed my express server on vercel. The project is just for fun.
I am trying to convert pdf to images and upload to database, supabase.
import { pdfToPng } from "pdf-to-png-converter";

const convertPdfToImg = async (filePath: string, output: string) => {
  const pngPage = await pdfToPng(filePath, {
    viewportScale: 2.0,
    outputFileMask: "buffer",
    outputFolder: output,
  });
  return pngPage;
};

export default convertPdfToImg;


and this is how I use
      const pdfBuffer = req.file.buffer;

      const tempDir = path.join("/tmp", "temp");
      if (!fs.existsSync(tempDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(tempDir, { recursive: true });
      }

      const pdfFilePath = path.join(tempDir, `${req.file.originalname}.pdf`);
      fs.writeFileSync(pdfFilePath, pdfBuffer);

      const content = await convertPdfToImg(pdfFilePath, tempDir);

I worked locally but after deployed I got the error, it say
"Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.mjs' imported from /var/task/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.mjs"."

I already try to use a lot of packages some of packages need to install extra libraries globally like "imagemagick"
